# Show results with zero textScore Mongoose $text search

Tags: mongodb, search, text, mongoose

```
recipe.find({
    $text: {
        $search: req.query.search,
        $diacriticSensitive: true
    }
}, {
    score: {
        $meta: "textScore"
    }
}
,function(err, data) { });
```

I am using mongoose text search functionality to sort the result based on their score. I also need to list the non matching records to the bottom of the list. Can i achieve this ? 
Is there any way to display recods with zero score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return all documents from 'recipe', even non-matching ones, by doing 'OR'  on a text search and a statement that always returns true. The non-matching results will receive a score of 0. A side effect of this seems to be that Mongo does not want to sort by the text score (if you try to sort on a mongo console), but this should not be a problem in your case since you can easily sort in the client (e.g., using lodash etc). Sample code (not tested):

```
recipe.find({
        $or: [{
            $text: {
                $search: req.query.search,
                $diacriticSensitive: true
            }
        }, {
            _id: {
                $exists: true
            }
        }]
    }, {
        score: {
            $meta: "textScore"
        }
    },
    function(err, data) {
        if (data) {
            data = _.map(data, function(d) {
                return d.toObject();
            });
            data = _.orderBy(data, ['score'], ['desc']);
        }
    }
);
```